# Android Socket.Inputstream Not responding to any data sends

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, client

I am having problem with inputstream in the socket module

```
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Connection is established, the Outputstream is also working Fine.

for some absurd reason i'm not able to get any resposne through "*InputStream*", wrapping my head around this things for three days, but couldn't able get the angle of my problem.

Tried using **scanner** ,but no luck.

Using ip = 10.0.2.2 and port 8080 on the clientSide
And ip = localhost and port 8080 on the ServerSide

I am on **Android Studio Bubblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2**
and *minimum android version* set to **Oreo**(27).

***ClientSocketAPK***

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.testsocket2;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;
    
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Thread Thread1 = null;
        EditText etIP, etPort;
        TextView tvMessages;
        EditText etMessage;
        Button btnSend;
        String SERVER_IP;
        int SERVER_PORT;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            etIP = findViewById(R.id.etIP);
            etPort = findViewById(R.id.etPort);
            tvMessages = findViewById(R.id.tvMessages);
            etMessage = findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
            btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
            Button btnConnect = findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
            btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tvMessages.setText("");
                    SERVER_IP = etIP.getText().toString().trim();
                    SERVER_PORT = Integer.parseInt(etPort.getText().toString().trim());
                    Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                    Thread1.start();
                }
            });
            btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String message = etMessage.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                        new Thread(new Thread3(message)).start();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        private PrintWriter output;
        private BufferedReader input;
        class Thread1 implements Runnable {
            public void run() {
                Socket socket;
                try {
                    socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
                    output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tvMessages.setText("Connected\n");
                        }
                    });
                    new Thread(new Thread2()).start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        class Thread2 implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        final String message = input.readLine();
                        if (message != null) {
                            Log.i("Debug Info on Input","Right Here =>");
                            Log.i("Debug Info on Input", String.valueOf(message));
                            Log.i("Debug Info on Input","Ends Here =>");;
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    tvMessages.append("server: " + message + "\n");
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                            Thread1.start();
                            return;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        class Thread3 implements Runnable {
            private String message;
            Thread3(String message) {
                this.message = message;
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {
                output.write(message);
                output.flush();
                Log.d("Debug Info on Output","Right Here =>");
                Log.d("Debug Info on Output", String.valueOf(message));
                Log.d("Debug Info on Output","Ends Here =>");;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvMessages.append("client: " + message + "\n");
                        etMessage.setText("");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
   <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:layout_margin = "16dp"
        tools:context = ".MainActivity">
        <EditText
            android:id = "@+id/etIP"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:hint = "IP-Address"
            android:inputType = "text" />
        <EditText
            android:id = "@+id/etPort"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_below = "@+id/etIP"
            android:hint = "Port No"
            android:inputType = "number" />
        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/btnConnect"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_below = "@+id/etPort"
            android:layout_gravity = "center"
            android:layout_marginTop = "16dp"
            android:text = "Connect To Server" />
        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/tvMessages"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_above = "@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_below = "@+id/btnConnect"
            android:inputType = "textMultiLine"
            android:textAppearance = "@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
        <EditText
            android:id = "@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_above = "@+id/btnSend"
            android:hint = "Enter Message"
            android:inputType = "text" />
        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
            android:text = "SEND" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.testsocket2">
            <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:exported="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>
        
        </manifest>
```

Comment: You use .readLine() to read a .. line. But is the server sending one? What exactly is it that the server sends?

Comment: @blackapps the Server is sending json file in the form of text with UTF-8 as a format, but also tried Scanner instead of buffer and UTF_8() to read.

Comment: I still dont know if that is send as a line or more lines. Or how. You know what it means.. a line? You are trying to read a line.

Comment: A "line" is something that ends with a linefeed character. Read the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()): *Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), a carriage return followed immediately by a line feed, or by reaching the end-of-file (EOF).*